# Should I wait after searching for elements and/or scrolling while web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to understand when to wait during a simple python/selenium web scraping script. I'm pulling titles and links for the top 100 results for approximately 50 search terms. I understand some waits are needed to ensure the page content has loaded, and other waits are needed to mimic human behavior (to avoid getting blocked by Google).

1. Do these `find_elements()` and `find_element()` calls interact with the server? In other words, should wait after these calls (for both reasons mentioned previously)?

```
#get whatever tags 
div_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, parentDivXPath)
title = div_element.find_element(By.XPATH, titleXPath)
```

2. Same question for scrolling, since I just noticed Google is now using infinite scroll. (I can swear it wasn't just yesterday! Am/was I hallucinating??) So now I need to implement scrolling, and I want to know if scrolling with JavaScript will interact with the server? I'm guessing I should also wait here since infinite scroll needs to load content from the server?

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Comment: No, `find_element` does not interact with the server, so you don't need to wait.

Comment: AMAZING. The script I was given took so long to run, and now it takes seconds. And hopefully I won't need to deal with scrolling for just 100 results.